# In the list of flagged posts, the question author is not rendered correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

In the list of [flagged posts](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged), the author of a question is rendered as shown in the following screenshot. (I removed the part revealing the OP, which is normally rendered.)

[image: screenshot]

The graphic covers "asked Apr 8 at 17:21" (if I read it correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.